# Calculating Reorder Quantity

Tags: forecasting

I am using the Holts Winter Forecasting Model to predict 1 period, and all the results from testing various items have U-Stat Scores below 1.

I already know average and variability for supplier lead time for each item.

What formula can I use to include the supplier lead time average, sd, and also the projected sales forecast

Known Variables
Supplier Lead Time + Sd 
1 period out for projected sales
Current On Hand Inventory

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an operations research question, but the classic model would be a (Q,r) inventory model based on the Economic Order Quantity and a re-order point to allow for safety stock because of the variation in lead time / demand.

This link on Inventory Theory has some good outlines of the models:
http://www.ime.unicamp.br/~andreani/MS515/capitulo12.pdf

However these models are based around optimizing the costs incurred, and include variables such as order cost, warehousing cost, and shortage costs. If these costs aren't explicit for you, you'll have to modify the models to suit you.

Do you know what distribution best fits your sales data? Finding the best distribution is key in setting the level of safety stock you'll need to meet your desired service levels.